# Comparing acidic strength of ortho and para hydroxybenzoic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds

In orthohydroxybenzoic acid intramolecular forces operate which I believe tend to lock the position thereby making acidic H not available for release whereas in parahydroxybenzoic acid there in no intramolecular force so h is relatively more available so I believe that para should be more acidic than ortho but the answer is reverse

---

[Why is ortho-hydroxybenzoic acid more acidic than its para-isomer?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/91076/98176) this qo. Though talks about it but does not resolve my query

Comment: Please structure your question, it gives the reader a headache. It would say it is one sentence, except it isn't, it is a typed down stream of thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the below scheme depicts well how the intramolecular hydrogen bonding more favours the collapse of the carboxylic O—H bond in the orthohydroxybenzoic acid than in the parahydroxybenzoic acid.
[image]

Comment: This is correct but the dictionary is quite personal. One has to say that the conjugated base in the ortho isomer is stabilised by a H bridge bond, involving a relatively stable 6 members ring.